# FTP command line batch script with regular expression

Tags: regex, command-line, ftp

I'm looking for an FTP tool that runs with the command line from Windows.
I am trying to connect to a server and download files that match a specified regular expression, and then delete them afterwards.

I started looking at Windows FTP command line tool - it does allow the script file, but the commands don't appear to support regular expressions... only single files or file masks (e.g. *.txt)

Does anyone know of any such ftp clients that support this? Or am I left with looking at writing my own (e.g. in a .Net library and use regex on listing outputs and issuing individual get and delete requests?). (And if I can't do this in a simple batch file, maybe I can get some recommendations on .Net libraries that support ftp clients?)

Free, of course, would be ideal too, :)

Thank you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could install Perl (free: Strawberry Perl or ActiveState Perl) and then use the following program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;
my $server = 'your.server.here';
my $user = 'my_username';
my $pass = 'my_secret';
my $pattern = qr{\.exe$}; # perl regex, this matches *.exe

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($server) or die "connect failed: $!";
$ftp->login($user,$pass) or die "login failed";
## maybe do $ftp->cwd(...) to change working dir
my @files = $ftp->ls; # directory listing;
@files = grep { m{$pattern} } @files or die "no matching files found";

for my $file (@files) {
    $ftp->get($file) or die "download $file failed";
    $ftp->delete($file) or die "delete $file failed";
}
```